# Rust nested closure moves and multiple owners

Tags: rust

Here is a MWE of the issue I am having, which does not compile:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
use nom::{
    IResult,
    error::VerboseError,
    bytes::complete::is_not,
    character::complete::space1,
    combinator::map,
    multi::separated_list1,
};

type Set = HashSet<char>;
fn _make_parser(reducer: impl Fn(Set, Set) -> Set) -> impl Fn(&str) -> IResult<&str, Set, VerboseError<&str>> {
    move |input| {
        map(
            separated_list1(
                space1,
                is_not(" \t"),
            ),
            |vec: Vec<&str>| {
                vec.iter().map(|s| s.chars().collect::<Set>())
                    .reduce(reducer).unwrap()
            }
        )(input)
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Do nothing");
}
```

Though not important, `_make_parser` is intended to create and return a `nom` parser function that will take a space-delimited set of strings like the following:

```
abc acdsodin ac azcefgd
```

The parser should then convert each string to a set (i.e. a `HashSet`) of `char` and apply some operation across the sets, passed as the `reducer` closure to `_make_parser`. This closure is intended to call something like `HashSet::union` or `HashSet::intersection`.

The code fails to compile with the following errors:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `reducer`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
  --> src/main.rs:21:33
   |
12 |     fn _make_parser(reducer: impl Fn(Set, Set) -> Set) -> impl Fn(&str) -> IResult<&str, Set, VerboseError<&str>> {
   |                     ------- captured outer variable
...
21 |                         .reduce(reducer).unwrap()
   |                                 ^^^^^^^ move occurs because `reducer` has type `impl Fn(Set, Set) -> Set`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0507]: cannot move out of `reducer`, a captured variable in an `Fn` closure
  --> src/main.rs:19:17
   |
12 |     fn _make_parser(reducer: impl Fn(Set, Set) -> Set) -> impl Fn(&str) -> IResult<&str, Set, VerboseError<&str>> {
   |                     ------- captured outer variable
...
19 |                 |vec: Vec<&str>| {
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move out of `reducer` occurs here
20 |                     vec.iter().map(|s| s.chars().collect::<Set>())
21 |                         .reduce(reducer).unwrap()
   |                                 -------
   |                                 |
   |                                 move occurs because `reducer` has type `impl Fn(Set, Set) -> Set`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |                                 move occurs due to use in closure
```

Clearly all the action is in the `_make_parser` function, and we've got a lot of closures going on. Let's call the closure returned by `_make_parser` the *parser* closure and the closure passed to the `nom` `map` combinator the *map* closure.

What I *think* is happening is that, the `reducer` closure (or more accuracy the implicit environment struct associated with the closure) is moved into the parser closer since we used the `move` keyword. This is what we want since we need the `reducer` closure to outlive the `_make_parser` function. It then seems like `reducer` is also being moved into the map closure, which is fine as well since we don't need it within the parser closure except inside of the map closure. It also seems like the `reduce` method is also trying to take ownership of `reducer` as well (I tried to make this a borrow from the map closure but it won't accept it). This seems like it should not be a problem because the map closure is really called only once. However the type of the closure taken by `map` combinator is a `FnMut` since in certain situations this could be called more than once (e.g. if the `map` combinator was nested inside a repeating combinator). My suspicion is that this is problematic because `reducer` is getting moved into the `reduce` method, which precludes calling the map closure more than once.

Is my interpretation of the error message correct, or is my understanding of the situation way off? If so how could this be solved? It seems like maybe it could be solved using reference counting to support multiple owners but, since `reduce` needs a closure and not an `Rc<closure>` I could not get this to work. Note that I am just learning Rust and haven't really used reference counters yet, though I *think* I basically understand how they work.

Lastly, note that this compiles just fine if I change the `reducer` type in the `_make_parser` to a normal `fn` instead of a closure `Fn`, which I think makes sense since in that case there is no implicit environment struct to worry about moving. This would even work fine for my actual purpose since I don't actually need to capture any environment in my `reducer`. However, I read that its better (i.e. more general) to accept closures instead of normal functions, and I'm also just really curious how this could be made to work with `_make_parser` accepting a closure or whether it's just not possible for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that your `reducer` cannot be copied or cloned, but is used inside another closure, which **moves** it out of itself because of that.

Your closure `move |input| {}` captures `reducer` and passes it as argument to `reduce()`. But as you know, Rust has **move** semantics, so every time you pass something as argument, the compiler will **move** it. Thus making your closure being able to be called only once, but it has the type `Fn` which by contract requires it to be callable multiple times.

So in order to solve the issue, you either have to be able to copy or clone the `reducer` closure. Given that you've said that it can be a simple `fn` in your case, then you can simply make it `Copy`:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
use nom::{
    IResult,
    error::VerboseError,
    bytes::complete::is_not,
    character::complete::space1,
    combinator::map,
    multi::separated_list1,
};

type Set = HashSet<char>;
fn _make_parser(reducer: impl Copy + Fn(Set, Set) -> Set) -> impl Fn(&str) -> IResult<&str, Set, VerboseError<&str>> {
    move |input| {
        map(
            separated_list1(
                space1,
                is_not(" \t"),
            ),
            |vec: Vec<&str>| {
                vec.iter().map(|s| s.chars().collect::<Set>())
                    .reduce(reducer).unwrap()
            }
        )(input)
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Do nothing");
}
```

Alternatively, if you capture non-`Copy` types from the environment you can make it `Clone` in order to make it less restrictive and pass a clone as argument to `reduce`: `.reduce(reducer.clone)`

[Rust Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e5eb4aa2a1887feb504a796e31e1159d)